# How to add more Javascript buttons to multiple DIV Buttons

Tags: javascript, html

Some of my buttons aren't displaying the proper code. For example; when I click iPhone, iPhone 5S the proper names show up with a 1, example: "AT&T1", at the end but when I click iPhone 5 it still shows the names with the with the 1 at the end instead of a 2, example: AT&T2,. It does that with the other buttons also in that row also. Can someone explain to me what I have to do the the javascript code when I want to add another set of button to the same or different buttons?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<table>
<td>
<a href="#" onclick="javascript:showHide(1);"><button>iPhone</button></a>
<a href="#" onclick="javascript:showHide(2);"><button>Cell Phone</button></a>
<a href="#" onclick="javascript:showHide(3);"><button>iPad</button></a>
<a href="#" onclick="javascript:showHide(3);"><button>iPod</button></a>
<a href="#" onclick="javascript:showHide(4);"><button>Tablet</button></a>
<a href="#" onclick="javascript:showHide(5);"><button>Macbook</button></a>
<a href="#" onclick="javascript:showHide(6);"><button>Mac</button></a>
</td>
</table>

<div id="level1item1" style="display: none;">

<button onclick="subShowHide('1');">iPhone 5S</button>
<button onclick="subShowHide('1');">iPhone 5</button>
<button onclick="subShowHide('1');">iPhone 4S</button>
<button onclick="subShowHide('1');">iPhone 4</button>
<button onclick="subShowHide('1');">iPhone 3GS</button>
 <button onclick="subShowHide('1');">iPhone 3</button>

</div>

<div id="level1item2" style="display: none;">
<button>HTC</button>
<button>Nokia</button>
<button>Motorola</button>
<button>Blackberry</button>
<button>Samsung</button>
<button>LG</button>
</div>

<div id="level1item3" style="display: none;">
<button>iPad Mini</button>
<button>iPad 4th Generation</button>
<button>iPad 3rd Generation</button>
<button>iPad 2nd Generation</button>
<button>iPad 1st Generation</button>
</div>

<div id="level1item4" style="display: none;">
<button>Apple</button>
<button>Amazon</button>
<button>Asus</button>
<button>Google</button>
<button>Microsoft</button>
<button>Samsung</button>
</div>

<div id="level1item5" style="display: none;">
<button>Macbook</button>
<button>Macbook Air</button>
<button>Macbook Pro</button>
</div>
<div id="level1item6" style="display: none;">
<button>iMac</button>
<button>Mac Mini</button>
<button>Mac Pro</button>
</div>

<div id="level1item7" style="display: none;">
<button>Touch</button>
<button>Nano</button>
<button>Classic</button>
</div>

<div id="level2item1" style="display: none;" name="iphone5S">
<button onclick="subSubShowHide('1');">AT&T1</button>
<button onclick="subSubShowHide('1');">Sprint1</button>
<button onclick="subSubShowHide('1');">Verizon1</button>
<button onclick="subSubShowHide('1');">T-Mobile1</button>
<button onclick="subSubShowHide('1');">Unlocked1</button>
<button onclick="subSubShowHide('1');">Other1</button>
</div>

<div id="level2item2" style="display: none;" name="iphone5">
<button onclick="subSubShowHide('1');">AT&T2</button>
<button onclick="subSubShowHide('1');">Sprint2</button>
<button onclick="subSubShowHide('1');">Verizon2</button>
<button onclick="subSubShowHide('1');">T-Mobile2</button>
<button onclick="subSubShowHide('1');">Unlocked2</button>
<button onclick="subSubShowHide('1');">Other2</button>
</div>

<div id="level2item2" style="display: none;" name="iphone4S">
<button onclick="subSubShowHide('1');">AT&T3</button>
<button onclick="subSubShowHide('1');">Sprint13</button>
<button onclick="subSubShowHide('1');">Verizon3</button>
<button onclick="subSubShowHide('1');">T-Mobile3</button>
<button onclick="subSubShowHide('1');">Unlocked3</button>
<button onclick="subSubShowHide('1');">Other3</button>
</div>

<div id="level2item1" style="display: none;" name="iphone4">
<button onclick="subSubShowHide('1');">AT&T4</button>
<button onclick="subSubShowHide('1');">Sprint4</button>
<button onclick="subSubShowHide('1');">Verizon4</button>
<button onclick="subSubShowHide('1');">T-Mobile4</button>
<button onclick="subSubShowHide('1');">Unlocked4</button>
<button onclick="subSubShowHide('1');">Other4</button>
</div>

<div id="level2item4" style="display: none;" name="iphone3gs">
<button onclick="subSubShowHide('1');">AT&T4</button>
<button onclick="subSubShowHide('1');">Unlocked4</button>
</div>

<div id="level2item5" style="display: none;" name="iphone3">
<button onclick="subSubShowHide('1');">AT&T5</button>
<button onclick="subSubShowHide('1');">Unlocked5</button>
</div>

<div id="level2item1" style="display: none;" name="iphone5S">
<button onclick="subSubShowHide('1');">AT&T6</button>
<button onclick="subSubShowHide('1');">Sprint6</button>
<button onclick="subSubShowHide('1');">Verizon6</button>
<button onclick="subSubShowHide('1');">T-Mobile6</button>
<button onclick="subSubShowHide('1');">Unlocked6</button>
<button onclick="subSubShowHide('1');">Other6</button>
</div>

<div id="level3item1" style="display: none;" name="at&t1">
<button onclick="subSubShowHide('1');">Apple iPhone 5S 16GB (AT&T)</button>
<button onclick="subSubShowHide('1');">Apple iPhone 5S 32GB (AT&T)</button>
<button onclick="subSubShowHide('1');">Apple iPhone 5S 64GB (AT&T)</button>
</div>

<div id="level3item2" style="display: none;" name="sprint1">
<button onclick="subSubShowHide('1');">Apple iPhone 5 16GB (AT&T)</button>
<button onclick="subSubShowHide('1');">Apple iPhone 5 32GB (AT&T)</button>
<button onclick="subSubShowHide('1');">Apple iPhone 5 64GB (AT&T)</button>
</div>

<div id="level3item3" style="display: none;" name="verizon1">
<button onclick="subSubShowHide('1');">Apple iPhone 4S 16GB (AT&T)</button>
<button onclick="subSubShowHide('1');">Apple iPhone 4S 32GB (AT&T)</button>
<button onclick="subSubShowHide('1');">Apple iPhone 4S 64GB (AT&T)</button>
</div>

<div id="level3item1" style="display: none;" name="t-mobile1">
<button onclick="subSubShowHide('1');">Apple iPhone 4 8GB (AT&T)</button>
<button onclick="subSubShowHide('1');">Apple iPhone 4 16GB (AT&T)</button>
<button onclick="subSubShowHide('1');">Apple iPhone 4 32GB (AT&T)</button>
</div>

<div id="level3item2" style="display: none;" name="unlocked1">
<button onclick="subSubShowHide('1');">Apple iPhone 3GS 8GB (AT&T)</button>
<button onclick="subSubShowHide('1');">Apple iPhone 3GS 16GB (AT&T)</button>
<button onclick="subSubShowHide('1');">Apple iPhone 3GS 32GB (AT&T)</button>
</div>

<div id="level3item3" style="display: none;" name="other1">
<button onclick="subSubShowHide('1');">Apple iPhone 3 8GB (AT&T)</button>
<button onclick="subSubShowHide('1');">Apple iPhone 3 16GB (AT&T)</button>
</div>

<script>
function showHide(obj) {
for(i=1;i<=1;i++){
    document.getElementById('qq'+i).style.display = 'none';
}
for(i=1;i<=1;i++){
    document.getElementById('qqq'+i).style.display = 'none';
}
for(i=1;i<=4;i++){
    if (i == obj) {
        document.getElementById('q'+i).style.display = 'block';
    } else {
        document.getElementById('q'+i).style.display = 'none';
    }
}
return false;
}
function subShowHide(obj){
for(i=1;i<=1;i++){
    document.getElementById('qqq'+i).style.display = 'none';
}
for(i=1;i<=1;i++){
    if (i == obj) {
        document.getElementById('qq'+i).style.display = 'block';
    } else {
        document.getElementById('qq'+i).style.display = 'none';
    }
}
return false;
}
function subSubShowHide(obj){
for(i=1;i<=1;i++){
    if (i == obj) {
        document.getElementById('qqq'+i).style.display = 'block';
    } else {
        document.getElementById('qqq'+i).style.display = 'none';
    }
}
return false;
}
</script>

</html>
```

http://jsbin.com/ITINowI/1/edit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your HTML is all messed:

- You shouldn't be using table for that, but UL (list) instead
- Table must have rows, you skipping TR elements
- You not supposed to use buttons inside anchors
- The onclick should be on your button element not on the anchor
- The inline "onclick" attribute dont need pseudo "javascript:" information

Despite all these problems, your code should be pointing to each subMenuID:

```
<button onclick="subShowHide('1');">iPhone 5S</button>
<button onclick="subShowHide('2');">iPhone 5</button>
<button onclick="subShowHide('3');">iPhone 4S</button>
<button onclick="subShowHide('4');">iPhone 4</button>
<button onclick="subShowHide('5');">iPhone 3GS</button>
 <button onclick="subShowHide('6');">iPhone 3</button>
```

Your javascript must interate for those IDs, the FOR was looping only in the first one (i=1;i<=1;i++)

[Fix a little Here](http://jsbin.com/ITINowI/5/edit) but I see you cut and paste to much code, repeated the same IDs and your subSubMenus are all misconfigured in the HTML, each item should have a correct pointing subID (all are pointing to ID 1)

Answer (score 1):

ID Attribute of html elements is supposed to be unique you have  multiple divs with same id `level1item1` so when you select div with `JS` or `jquery` the first div with the id is selected thats whay you see this behavior try to use the class attribute to assign multiple divs

Samne for `level1item2,level1item3,level1item4,level1item5,level1item6 ....`

Comment: The ID's are different. They have level1item1, level2item2, and so on.

Comment: Could you please provide me with an example? I'm a bit confused because the give should give them a distinct value.

Comment: you can use CTRL+F :) i  found multiple ids from your jsbincode

Comment: Could you elaborate or provide and example? @dianuj

Comment: @user2680614 pay attention! You do have repeated IDs. Those are the evils of Copy & Paste...

Comment: @HanletEscaño I am paying attention. I'm not an expert like you guys, I'm new to this! Can you explain to me how the ID's, level1item2 and level1item3 are the same? The 2 and the 3 should make them different ID's.

Comment: @user2680614, from iphone5 on, those divs have repeated id.